# Is there an xkeymacs equivalent in Mac?

Tags: keyboard, emacs

In PC, the utility of xkeymacs.exe enables one to use emacs key in every case. Does Mac have the similar utility? For example, is there a utility that I can use key 'C-x C-s' to send the key 'Command-S'?

Comment: You do know that many emacs keybindings just work in OS X apps, right? C-a and C-e, for example, move to front and end of a text line in TextEdit, the Safari URL bar, etc.

Comment: @mankoff : Yes, I do. However, I just wanted to know if I can have 'C-x C-s' also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: It looks like there is a solution described [here](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/060620.html).

---

I don't **know** of a solution, but I'd bet if anything could do this, it would be [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele&_sc=1).

> Ukelele can assign multiple-character
>   strings and can create "dead keys",
>   where a keystroke sets a new state
>   that modifies the output of the
>   following keystroke.

Possibly combined with an Automator app. The initial keystroke <kbd>C-x</kbd> initiates the app, it captures the secondary keystroke (<kbd>C-s</kbd>), uses a lookup table to convert <kbd>C-s</kbd> to <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, and then passes that to the foreground app.

Answer (score 2):

You could configure some of them in `~/Library/Keybindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`. See [hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/cocoa-text.html) and this sample file: [Emacs Opt Bindings.dict](http://hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/KeyBindings/Emacs%20Opt%20Bindings.dict).

Another option would be to use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://mac.pqrs.org/keyremap4macbook/). It supports over 1000 [preconfigured keybindings](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/list.html), including an "Emacs Mode" section.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know xkeymap, but it sounds like you want to do keyboard mapping. Mac OS is built on BSD, hence [`xmodmap`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/xmodmap.1.html) should work...